# reposition array elements based on a condition in php

Tags: php, arrays

So I have this array:

```
$dates[0] = array('start'=>'2010-07-22', 'end'=>'2010-07-23');
$dates[1] = array('start'=>'2010-07-22', 'end'=>'0000-00-00');
$dates[2] = array('start'=>'2010-07-29', 'end'=>'0000-00-00');
$dates[3] = array('start'=>'2010-07-31', 'end'=>'2010-07-31');
$dates[4] = array('start'=>'2010-07-08', 'end'=>'2010-07-31');
$dates[5] = array('start'=>'2010-08-01', 'end'=>'2010-09-30');
$dates[6] = array('start'=>'2010-07-18', 'end'=>'2010-08-15');
$dates[7] = array('start'=>'2010-07-01', 'end'=>'2010-08-31');
```

and i have the following condition:
`if an element 'start' is less then today, took the element's attribute 'end' and position the element relative to the others elements 'start'`

So if an event `started yesterday` and `ends tomorrow` it should appear after the events `beginning today`

so the resulting array is something like this:

```
$dates[3] = array('start'=>'2010-07-22', 'end'=>'2010-07-23');
$dates[4] = array('start'=>'2010-07-22', 'end'=>'0000-00-00');
$dates[5] = array('start'=>'2010-07-29', 'end'=>'0000-00-00');
$dates[6] = array('start'=>'2010-07-31', 'end'=>'2010-07-31');
$dates[1] = array('start'=>'2010-07-08', 'end'=>'2010-07-31');
$dates[7] = array('start'=>'2010-08-01', 'end'=>'2010-09-30');
$dates[2] = array('start'=>'2010-07-18', 'end'=>'2010-08-15');
$dates[0] = array('start'=>'2010-07-01', 'end'=>'2010-08-31');
```

How could i go from the sample input to the sample output?

[EDIT]

1. I'm trying to change the output of [EventList](http://www.schlu.net/) a component for Joomla
2. I'm not a native english speaker

So, I'll try again:

if the event start date is minor than today then order the event relative to `this event enddate` and the `others events startday`

Ex:

If the event 'A' started on 2010-07-01 and finish on 2010-07-25 and event 'B' starts on 2010-07-24 and the current date is 2010-07-20 then event 'A' comes after event 'B'

If the event 'A' starts on 2010-07-20 and finish on 2010-07-25 and event 'B' starts on 2010-07-24 and the current date is 2010-07-20 then event 'B' comes after event 'A'

I 'hope' it's a little more clearer now.

Comment: I don't quite understand the requirement, but studying the input and output makes me to realize that you are just sorting by date, and giving precedence for those with an end-date. *smells homework*

Comment: @yclian: re: smells homework.  from taking a look at the flood of php posts today all from relatively new users, I think you may be right.  Finals time?  Either that or PHP has started its "Testfest".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, so if I understand correctly: sort by stardate if >=today, enddate if startdate <= today.

```
function _myDateSorter($a,$b){
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $adate = ($a['start'] >= $date) ? $a['start'] : $a['end'];
    $bdate = ($b['start'] >= $date) ? $b['start'] : $b['end'];
    if($adate =='0000-00-00') $adate = '9999-99-99';//sort after it appears
    if($bdate =='0000-00-00') $bdate = '9999-99-99';//sort after it appears
    if($adate == $bdate) return 0;
    return $adate > $bdate ? 1 : -1;
}

uasort($dates,'_myDateSorter');
```