# php rearrange array values based on condition

Tags: php

basically i have this array:

```
array(
'08:00-08:40' => array(
    't' => '39',
    'sub' => 'COMP'
),
'08:40-09:20' => array(
    't' => '17',
    'sub' => 'KIS'
),
'09:20-10:00' => array(
    't' => '36',
    'sub' => 'B/ST'
),
'10:20-11:00' => array(
    't' => '7',
    'sub' => 'ENG'
),
'11:00-11:40' => array(
    't' => '36',
    'sub' => 'B/ST'
),
'11:40-12:20' => array(
    't' => '31',
    'sub' => 'HIS'
),
'12:20-13:00' => array(
    't' => '26',
    'sub' => 'PHY'
),
'14:00-14:40' => array(
    't' => '33',
    'sub' => 'GEO'
),
'14:40-15:20' => array(
    't' => '31',
    'sub' => 'HIS'
),
'15:20-16:00' => array(
    't' => '20',
    'sub' => 'BIO'
)
```

)

My requirement is that if an **element['sub']** appears twice in the whole array then both instances should be next to each other in the array.

so for the above array i expect to have the following output:

```
array(
'08:00-08:40' => array(
    't' => '39',
    'sub' => 'COMP'
),
'08:40-09:20' => array(
    't' => '17',
    'sub' => 'KIS'
),
'09:20-10:00' => array(
    't' => '36',
    'sub' => 'B/ST'
),
'10:20-11:00' => array(
    't' => '36',
    'sub' => 'B/ST'
),
'11:00-11:40' => array(
    't' => '7',
    'sub' => 'ENG'
),
'11:40-12:20' => array(
    't' => '31',
    'sub' => 'HIS'
),
'12:20-13:00' => array(
    't' => '31',
    'sub' => 'HIS'
),
'14:00-14:40' => array(
    't' => '26',
    'sub' => 'PHY'
),
'14:40-15:20' => array(
    't' => '33',
    'sub' => 'GEO'
),
'15:20-16:00' => array(
    't' => '20',
    'sub' => 'BIO'
)
```

)

i cant figure out how to adapt [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286006/reposition-array-elements-based-on-a-condition-in-php)  to my case..any help much appreciated

Comment: Why don't you just sort the array based on the `sub` values? That will put all the ones with the same value next to each other.

Comment: @Barmar i have edited the title and body of the question..sorting will rearrange the elements but i only want the values to be rearranged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by sorting the values based on the `sub` element. To keep the keys in the original order, you can save them in another array, then use `array_combine` to put it back together with the sorted array.

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
usort($array, function($x, $y) {
    if ($x['sub'] == $y['sub']) {
        return 0;
    } elseif ($x['sub'] < $y['sub']) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});
$array = array_combine($keys, $array);
```